# How to handle default value for logstash pipeline efficiently?

Tags: logstash

I have a logstash pipeline that its filter part looks like this:

```
    filter {

    if condition {
        prune {
            blacklist_names => ["^cat[1-8]$","^classifier.version$","^accessory_check$"]
        }
        http {
            url => aURL
            query =>  {
                // relevant parts
            }
            verb => GET
            body_format => "json"
            ecs_compatibility => "disabled"
             add_field => {
                 "cat1" => "%{[body][cat1]}"
                 "cat2" => "%{[body][cat2]}"
                 "cat3" => "%{[body][cat3]}"
                 "cat4" => "%{[body][cat4]}"
                 "cat5" => "%{[body][cat5]}"
                 "cat6" => "%{[body][cat6]}"
                 "cat7" => "%{[body][cat7]}"
                 "cat8" => "%{[body][cat8]}"
                 "accessory_check" => "%{[body][accessory_check]}"
                 "classifier.version" => "${CLASSIFIER_LATEST_VERSION}"
             }
            remove_field => ["body","headers","@timestamp","@version"]
        }
    }
}
```

As you know if for example `"%{[body][cat1]}"` be null then the value of `cat1` would be string `"%{[body][cat1]}"` . but I want the value of `cat1` be `""` instead of `"%{[body][cat1]}"`.

I could solve the problem by changing the pipeline like this:

```
      filter {
        if condition {
            prune {
                blacklist_names => ["^cat[1-8]$","^classifier.version$","^accessory_check$"]
            }
            http {
                url => aURL
                query =>  {
                  // relevant parts
                }
                verb => GET
                body_format => "json"
                ecs_compatibility => "disabled"
    #             add_field => {
    #                 "cat1" => "%{[body][cat1]}"
    #                 "cat2" => "%{[body][cat2]}"
    #                 "cat3" => "%{[body][cat3]}"
    #                 "cat4" => "%{[body][cat4]}"
    #                 "cat5" => "%{[body][cat5]}"
    #                 "cat6" => "%{[body][cat6]}"
    #                 "cat7" => "%{[body][cat7]}"
    #                 "cat8" => "%{[body][cat8]}"
    #                 "accessory_check" => "%{[body][accessory_check]}"
                      "classifier.version" => "${CLASSIFIER_LATEST_VERSION}"
    #             }
                remove_field => ["body","headers","@timestamp","@version"]
            }
        }
    
    
        if [body][cat1] {
                 mutate{    add_field => {"cat1" => "%{[body][cat1]}"}  }
            } else {
                mutate{    add_field => {"cat1" => ""}  }
            }
    
        if [body][cat2] {
             mutate{    add_field => {"cat2" => "%{[body][cat2]}"}  }
        } else {
            mutate{    add_field => {"cat2" => ""}  }
        }
      // and others 
}
```

but as you can see its ugly. I wonder is there any alternative that reaches me to the same goal?

Comment: Maybe with [mutate/rename](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename)? It's not supposed to fail if the field is missing, though I don't know if it can move fields like you want

Comment: @baudsp thank you. I don't understand how rename would help me out. if it is possible elaborate more or  if youcould give me an example that would be great. thanks alot.

Comment: Like this: `mutate { rename => { "[body][cat5]" => "cat5" } }`. Though you'd have to create all the empty fields beforehand (I had missed that requirement in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-handle-default-value-for-logstash-pipeline-efficiently/330335/1)

I ended up the following solution:

```
ruby {
     code => '
          event.to_hash.each { |k, v|
              if /^cat\d/.match(k) and /%{[^}]+}/.match(v)
                event.set(k, "none")
              elsif k == "accessory_check" and /%{[^}]+}/.match(v)
                event.set(k, "none")
              elsif k == "classifier.version" and /%{[^}]+}/.match(v)
                event.set(k, "none")
              end
          }
        '
     }
```